# Font Awesome (Chrome) - Icons loading in wrong place on Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

We have a page that has multiple icons in for various pieces of information, e.g. emails, phone numbers, mobiles etc.

These are setup on the first active Bootstrap Tab, and will load absolutely fine on the initial load.

However when you switch off of the tab, and then return, the icons all appear in the top left of the page, with a higher index than everything else as well.

Now the strange part is that some of the icons are pulling the text that should appear after them. This text is outside of the `<i>` tags with the FA classes.

This also only happens on Google Chrome, works fine on MS Edge.

The code for this page has not been edited, and worked perfectly in the past, the only thing that has changed is the latest version of Chrome. Due to this I don't know what code I can show that could possibly be wrong.

Pictures below:

[image: What it should look like]

[image: How it appears after switching to another tab and abck]

First picture displays what it should look like and DOES look like upon initial loading.

Second picture displays what happens when you switch to another tab and back.

So as far as we know, it is a Chrome specific issue. If anyone knows any different please correct me! Also if you know of a work around until the issue gets resolved, I'm open to suggestions.

// EDIT 1

HTML For header, loading of CSS Files

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/nhstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/chosen-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

HTML for client details box

```
<div class="col-lg-12 nopadding wow bounceInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
<div class="card-nopadding dashboard7daystats">
    <div class="header7day"><i class="fa fa-pie-chart fa-1x fa-fw"></i> Client Details</div>
    <div class="card-line-small"> 
    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-1x fa-fw"></i> Tel: <?php echo $client['client_tel']; ?></div>
    <div class="card-line-small"> 
    <i class="fa fa fa-random fa-1x fa-fw"></i> Email: <?php echo $client['client_email']; ?></div>
    <div class="card-line-small"> 
    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-1x fa-fw"></i> Fax: <?php echo $client['client_fax_num']; ?></div>
    <div class="card-line-small"> 
    <i class="fa fa-comments fa-1x fa-fw"></i> Division: <?php echo $client['division_name']; ?></div>
    <div class="card-line-small"> 
    <i class="fa fa-comments fa-1x fa-fw"></i> Industry: <?php echo $client['industry_name']; ?></div>
</div>
</div>
```

// EDIT 2

I have also just noticed that in regards to the text that also gets moved, the cursor still treats it as if it is in the same place, and proceeds to change to the I cursor, and allows me to highlight it from the same place.

Comment: can you please share your code at jsfiddle

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: I've added some, but like I said, there has been no changes to this page, and the site works flawlessly on other browsers, with Chrome being the only culprit.

Comment: I used your code with Chrome and I'm not getting your result, possible solutions: share your code, really or open Chrome's inspect element and search the css that is causing this